# how to create svg page like coin360 and market maps?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, sections

I have to create a front page like `coin360.com` which show market map and cryptocurrencies rates.

This page is made with SVG answer sections

os there a ready source for this template?
or how can I create something like that??

note: I don't need the backend concepts, only need the front.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Treemapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping). Googling 'svg treemap' brings up several solutions, among which is [the Github repo for the `svg-treemap` `npm` package](https://github.com/brendanmoore/svg-treemap).

Answer (score 0):

i think best thing you looking for is this:

[D3Plus](https://d3plus.org/?path=/story/charts-treemap--treemap&args=tile:binary)